# Element lying "on top" of another for no reason?

Tags: css, element

I'm just trying to put together a webpage for a client, and I have a photo gallery at the bottom of the page, but it seems to be on top of the rest of the page's content, although its own content appears underneath the rest. The easiest thing to do is see it for yourself [here.](http://www.bekonscot.co.uk/tv/talktalk/) *Note how you can't play the YouTube Video, if you use "inspect element you will see what I mean about "lying on top" *

I've spent at least an hour and half trying to fix this, and it’s been a long day! I may just be being tired, but some friendly advice would be gratefully received. I want to try and avoid a work around using z-index if I can!

Comment: You've set `#maincontent` to `float:left;` which takes it out of the document flow. In this instance, there's really no need for the float.

Comment: I've just removed the float on the elements #video and #video_about but its not displaying correctly. Any idea on alertenatives which may work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your `float`'s.

For example by adding `clear: both;` to the gallery:

```
.gallery {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have had to leave the floats in there though, otherwise it displays one below the other, is this bad CSS?

Comment: @tim.baker "is this bad CSS?" This question can't be answered, as it depends on a lot of characteristics. It is good CSS as long if it works for your layout and design and has comfortable loading times…